# Where did the files I burned to a DVD-RW go?

Tags: windows-7, dvd-burning

I used the built-in file burning function in Windows 7 to burn a set of .rar archives to a DVD-RW. It finished burning and ejected the disc. I put it back in and the drive shows a disk with 305 MB of 4.37 GB free so the files got written. When I browse to the DVD it doesn't show any files. Where did they go and how do I get to them?

[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe they are hidden

Comment: Good call! I never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

try to read the dvd under another OS (try linux)... maybe the dvd or the rar archives are damaged.

or try another burner ([cdburnerxp.se](http://cdburnerxp.se/) free and small app)

Comment: maybe the dvd or the rar archives are damaged

Comment: or try another burner (http://cdburnerxp.se/ free and small app)

Comment: You know, you can edit your question and add new content ;)

Comment: Good idea. I'll try it on my linux box.\